# update SKU on save using observer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, event-observer, adminhtml

On **Saving New/Old products** in **admin**, I am updating the SKU automatically with [PRODUCTID]-[COLOR] value.

I am able to update any attribute via observer, but when try to update SKU it gives me an error.  I am using 2.1.8 version and event observer.

I if use

`$this->action->updateAttributes([$id], ['ATTRIBUTE-name)' => "ANYVALUE"],$storeId);`   // It works,

if `Attribute = sku` , it fails.

```
Notice: Undefined index: value in \www\magento\vendor\magento\module-eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity.php on line 1567
```

This is my code

```
<?php
                namespace [NAMESPACE]\[MODULE]\Observer;

                class Productsaveafter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
                {    
                    protected $action;
                    protected $storemanager;

                    public function __construct(
                        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action $action,
                        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanager           
                    ){
                        $this->action = $action;
                        $this->storemanager = $storemanager;
                    }

                public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
                {
                    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
                    $id = $product->getId();   
                    $MYSKU = $id.'-RED'; // example  

                        $storeId = $this->storemanager->getStore()->getStoreId();                  
                    $this->action->updateAttributes([$id], ['sku' => $MYSKU],$storeId);

                        return $this;
                }

                ?>
```

Event XML:

```
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="myobserver_productsaveafter" instance="[NAMESPACE]\[MODULE]\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
```

DI XMl is empty

Does anybody can tell me what is wrong with my code or suggest another way to do this?